# GridView Linking column values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have two gridviews in seperate screens.

**GridView1**

```
 ID    Product    Date           Amount
 1       Car1     02/03/2014    $ 15,000
 1       Car2     05/03/2014    $ 10,000 
 2       Bike     01/01/2014    $  2,500
 3       Bus      06/04/2014    $ 25,000
```

**GridView2**

```
 ID    Product    Date           Amount
 1       Car2     05/03/2014    $ 25,000 
 2       Bike     01/01/2014    $  2,500
 3       Bus      06/04/2014    $ 25,000
```

Gridview2 sums up similar ID row values from GridView1 and displays in GridView2 picking the latest effective Date.

Now I am showing my ID column in GridView2 as LinkButton. When I click on value 1 in GridView2 ID column it has to navigate to GridView1 and show only values of ID 1 in the grid.

**Code Behind:**

GridView1

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = DataRepository.GetG1();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

public static DataTable GetG1()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "Select * from ManLog";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

**GridView2**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = DataRepository.GetG2();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }

public static DataTable GetG2()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "Select ID, Product, max(Date),sum(Amount) from ManLog";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

**Link Button for GridView 2:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="25%" />
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" Width="100%" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: as you say you have them in seperate screens. Does this mean that you have them also in different web forms? if yeap, please post the code behind code of this forms.

Comment: Yes they are in different forms. You want me to post all codes or just gridview binding.

Comment: just the gridview binding.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - Updated the post with my code.

Comment: as @joel told, its better to pass the ID as aquery string and get the value back based on that and bind it to your grid.

Comment: What's the url of the gridview1 page?

Comment: Its running in local host and the url is:   http://localhost:5005/Product%20Profit.aspx

Comment: @Vicky please see my updated post and tell me if your made the update like mine. thanks

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - When I add that I see the url showing up in gridview2 in ID column and when I click them I see no action happening.

Comment: @Vicky hm I found where is the problem. You use a LinkButton and not HyperLinkField, which would be more suitable in this case, since you only need a simple redirect. Do you want to use javascript, or you just want to add a LinkButton and set the NavigateUrl to the text we use before? I can tell you how you can proceed in both cases. Just let me know, which you prefer.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - first of all many thanks for your help. How abt we achieve this using LinkButton itself.

Comment: @Vicky you welcome. Check my update post now and if there is any ambiguity, please just let me know. thanks.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - I get this error. The page does not contain a definition for 'LinkButton_Click' and no extension method 'LinkButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: @Vicky have you added the LinkButton_Click method in the code behind class ? Also you should change the definition of the LinkButton to the one I posted on my update.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - I have added the click method in code behind. I get this error even after adding.

Comment: @Vicky have you define the access of method as protected. That's very important.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - yes its protected.

Comment: @Vicky hm very strange...Let me think about anything else and I hope I will come uo with some idea later.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - Yeah and lemme try if I can add do anything on this.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - I got it working:)

Comment: @Vicky i'm glad about it. how? what did you change?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - In the link button I have added this '<%# Eval("Code") %>' along with CommandArgument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `GetG1` method to the following one:

```
public static DataTable GetG1(int? id=null)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {
        conn.Open();

        if(id.HasValue)
        {
            string strQuery = "Select * From ManLog Where Id=@id";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            cmd.Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("id",id.Value);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            string strQuery = "Select * From ManLog";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Then as already Joel posted, you should pass an id to the link of your second gridview. For this reason you should update the Page_Load event handler of your first web form, where GridView1 resides.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int id;
        if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id)
        {

            GridView1.DataSource = DataRepository.GetG1(id);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = DataRepository.GetG1();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least you should update the corresponding links in GridView2.

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblEAICode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EAI_Code") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

At the Text attribute you should place `'../../gridview1.aspx?id=<%# Eval("EAI_Code") %>'`, where `../../gridview1.aspx` is the relative path of the web form in which gridview1 resides.

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EAI_Code") %>' OnCommand="LinkButton_Click" Text="View"> </asp:LinkButton>
```

add the following handler for the click event of your link button in your code behind class

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandArgument != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Product%20Profit.aspx?id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made by ID column in GridView2 as LinkButton. Buth when I click the values its not navigating to GridView1.

Comment: could you please post how you declare these links?

Comment: <ItemTemplate> <asp:LinkButton ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Have your tried the update of the Text attribute I suggested?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what exactly your question is or how your page is laid out, but I think you need to set the `url` in the `GridView2` link to something like `GridView1Page.aspx?id=1` then use that `QueryString` to only load the given id.  If you don't use the `url` or don't want to post, then try a `Session` variable.

So in your grid binding method you have something like:

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
    //load some: select * from table where id = Request.QueryString["id"] 
}
else
{
    //load all (select * from table)
}
```